# iOS app crash on CIDetectorAccuracyHigh

Tags: ios, face-detection

I ran into a really strange bug with code that worked without a hiccup for a long time. Face detection suddenly starts crashing on me (BAD_EXEC).

After some trial and error the only solve was to switch from `CIDetectorAccuracyHigh` to `CIDetectorAccuracyLow`, but those results are not as good.

Did anyone else ran into this?

Answer (score 0):

finally found out the reason.
Something was corrupt with my xcuserdata/ folder.
After deleting it everything runs fine.